# Microsoft Flow with File Created Action is not triggered all the time

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, onedrive, power-automate

I have one drive synced local folder and the files will be synced with a SharePoint site when we add files to this folder. I also have a Flow that gets triggered for every file added.

[image]

The detailed article about what I am achieving here can be found [here](https://medium.com/@sibeeshvenu/azure-form-recognizer-and-microsoft-flow-to-search-scanned-pdf-content-in-sharepoint-online-11b8f6d5dc1e).

The problem is that it is not triggered all the time. Let's say I added 100 files and the Flow triggered only 78 times. Are there any limitations on the Flow that it can run only this many times in a timeframe? Anyone else faced this issue? Any help is really appreciated.  #sharepoint #sharepointonline #flow #onedrive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after spending a few hours, I got it working with 120 files at the same time. The flow runs smoothly and efficiently now. Here is what I did.

Click on the three dots on your trigger in the flow, and then click on settings.

[image]

Now in the new screen, enable the Split On (Without this my Flow was not getting triggered) and give the Array value. Clicking on the array dropdown will give you the matching value.  Now turn on the Concurrency as shown in the preceding image and give the Degree of Parallelism to maximum (50 as of now).

[image]

According to Microsoft:

Concurrency Control is to Limit the number of concurrent runs of the flow or leave it off to run as many as possible at the same time. Concurrency control changes the way new runs are queued. It cannot be undone once enabled.